# Boinc Manager stuck in Ready to report status bar

Tags: ubuntu, server, iptables, boinc

I'm setttings up boinc manager on ubuntu server and remote from mac os dekstop.

my question is i use iptables in ubuntu server.

Boinc manager logs says: (BOINC can't access Internet - check network connection or proxy configuration.)

but the Boinc Manager says (Ready to report) stuck in iptables.

if i get full access it will upload it. so i'm 100% sure it is itpables

can some one help me with this?

Answer (score -1):

I found it:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 31416 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 31416 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```